# simple affine encryption using python problem

Tags: python, cryptography, python-cryptography

I'm a beginner to python I'm actually trying to encrypt a message using basic python

```
LETTERS = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V",
           "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
crpt = input("please enter your message")
K = 3
z = ""
r = ""
for i in range(len(crpt)):
    if crpt[i] not in LETTERS:
        LETTERS[r] = " "
        print(f"new encrypted letter: {LETTERS[r]}")
        z += LETTERS[r]

    else:
        icrpt = LETTERS.index(crpt[i])
        r = (icrpt * K) % 26
        print(f"new encrypted letter: {LETTERS[r]}")
        z += LETTERS[r]

print(f"the initial message is: {crpt}")
print(f"the new encrypted message is: {z}")
```

I realised that there is a bug where if the message is "A A A"
it only outputs "A   " as if the other A's are considered a space

i thought of making an if statement just for that case but it doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the statement LETTERS[r] = " " and  do not understand the purpose of it.
When you encrypt the first "A", r become 0.
Then you try to encrypt a space but there is no space character in your alphabet. So you execute the "if crypt ..." code and wipe-out your alphabet[0]. Next time you will try to encrypt a "A", the result will be a blank.
To conclude:

- you should not modify your alphabet. I don't understand why you included that statement.
- all lowercase letters in your unencrypted message won't be encrypted.